# C++ app missing winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::DataWriter

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

Been looking around for how to link a small program that references the DataWriter

My program references other objects (like the winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth class).   So I know it's not totally broken.

I have these two libs at the top of my cpp file, which got everything to link until I started using DataWriter.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "oleaut32")
#pragma comment(lib, "runtimeobject")
```

it compiles fine, but I have no idea what lib to include.   MS reference docs don't seem to mention the libraries you need to link with to use them:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datawriter

I tried searching (using dumpbin) all of the libraries on my system for it first before posting here.

```
auto writer = DataWriter();
writer.WriteString(L"HEREIAM");
```

EDIT: Added the actual linker error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::DataWriter::DataWriter(void)" (??0DataWriter@Streams@Storage@Windows@winrt@@QEAA@XZ)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned int __cdecl winrt::impl::consume_Windows_Storage_Streams_IDataWriter<struct winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::IDataWriter>::WriteString(struct winrt::param::hstring const &)const " (?WriteString@?$consume_Windows_Storage_Streams_IDataWriter@UIDataWriter@Streams@Storage@Windows@winrt@@@impl@winrt@@QEBAIAEBUhstring@param@3@@Z)
```

If there's some other way to create a Buffer with winrt, that'd be fine too.

Comment: What's the linker error you're getting?

Comment: @Sunius added them to the body

Comment: Which Windows SDK are you on? Those functions are defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt\winrt\Windows.Storage.Streams.h" on my machine. I wonder if some of your headers are corrupted or broken. They're inline, so you definitely don't need to link any libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only lib you need is "windowsapp.lib", although others will do for desktop/console apps. When you get a linker error like that it means that you failed to include a necessary header that provides the missing definition. Try including "winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h".

[Here's more info from the FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/faq#why-is-the-linker-giving-me-a-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-error).

Comment: windowsapp.lib didn't help, but the include fixed it thanks!   didn't realize there were separate includes for linker directives and object definitions.

Comment: @Erik Aronesty I think this should be marked as answer, I had the same trouble with many different functions